# Insert a foreign key values in mysql (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

hey guys i have a little problem. All i want is to insert a foreign key values in my table.
Here’s my create table statement in mysql.

```
CREATE TABLE `sales` (
 `sales_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `fkmember` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `date_of_sales` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`sales_id`),
 INDEX `fkmember` (`fkmember`),
 CONSTRAINT `sales_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fkmember`) REFERENCES `member` (`member_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3;


CREATE TABLE `sales_line` (
 `line_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `fkproduct` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `fksales` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `quantity_purchased` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `subtotal` FLOAT(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`line_id`),
 INDEX `fkproduct` (`fkproduct`),
 INDEX `fksales` (`fksales`),
 CONSTRAINT `sales_line_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fkproduct`) REFERENCES `product` (`product_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `sales_line_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fksales`) REFERENCES `sales` (`sales_id`)
)
```

my table structure:

sales table
sales_id   |  fkmember   |  date_of_sales   |

sales_line table
line_id   |  fkproduct   |  fksales   |  quantity_purchased   |  subtotal   |

my code in inserting the values in two tables:

```
foreach($products as $p){
        $data = array(
            'sales_id' => null,
            'fkmember' => $memberid
            'name' => $p['product_name']
        );
        $this->db->insert('sales',$data);
    }
   foreach($products as $p){
        $data = array(
            'line_id' => null,
            'fk_product' => $p['id'],
            'fk_sales' => null,
            'quantity_purchased' => $p['product_qty'],
            'subtotal' => number_format($subtotal,2)
        );
        $this->db->insert('sales_line',$data);
    }
    }
```

i know i have an error in inserting values in inserting values in fk_sales.
How can i insert a value in this field that comes from the id of my sales table?
Because i want to insert these two tables in one round. Please Help Me Guys. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this (notice the use of `$this->db->insert_id()` ):

```
    foreach($products as $p){
        $data = array(
            'sales_id' => null,
            'fkmember' => $memberid
            'name' => $p['product_name']
        );
        $this->db->insert('sales',$data);
    }

    $sales_insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    foreach($products as $p){
        $data = array(
            'line_id' => null,
            'fk_product' => $p['id'],
            'fk_sales' => $sales_insert_id,
            'quantity_purchased' => $p['product_qty'],
            'subtotal' => number_format($subtotal,2)
        );
        $this->db->insert('sales_line',$data);
    }
```

Comment: thanks guys it is really a big help to me. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Was it the right answer? If so, make sure you click the check mark next to the answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Codeigniter Database Helper guide here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html). The first function is $this->db->insert_id();

So you can use this like;

```
 $this->db->insert('sales',$data);
 $fk_sales_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

in your controller function, insert sales entry first, and return the sales id, then use the returned id to insert sales lines as below.

```
Eg: 
//Controller function

  //insert the sales record and get the sales id
  $sales_id = $this->model_sale->insert_sale($mameber_id, $product_name); 

foreach($products as $p)
{
  //insert sales line
  $this->model_sales_line->insert_sales_line($sales_id, $p['id'],$p['product_qty'],$sub_total);
}

//Sales Model

public function insert_sale($mameber_id, $product_name)
{
 $data = array(            
        'fkmember' => $memberid
        'name' => $p['product_name']
    );
    $this->db->insert('sales',$data);

   return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Don't forget to accept any of the answers if correct.